# How to make GAF Ridge Cap Shingles?

Tags: roof, shed, shingles

I have Timberline shingles but not the ridge cap ones

[image]

How do I "make" the ridge cap shingles? 
https://www.gaf.com/roofing/residential/products/ridge_cap_shingles

Since I don't have the 3-tab shingles. This is for a shed so I don't care much as long as it won't leak. Could I just cut to 1/3?

**UPDATE 1**
My shingle is metric so it's 39 3/8" long actually. So I am wondering if it is OK to cut it 13" for ridge edge shingle? Plus this has adhesive strip on the top (not center). I don't know if it matters (see highlight below as adhesive strip):

[image]

**UPDATE 2** (WRONG)

Illustration to use the top part only (the one with one layer). Cut to 1/3 and use the "x" pieces for ridge caps.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done just that in a pinch, but I recommend centering your tabs on an inset section (the part along the bottom half with only one layer). This will allow much easier bending over the ridge, and your nailing will have more structure as well. You'll use more shingles, but they'll install easier.

[image]

Cut at the red line. Fold in the center.

Comment: I had UPDATE 2 based on my understanding above. Would you please confirm that? Basically I would just use 1/3 of the top half. This method would require a lot of shingles, no?

Comment: No, you need the full height of the shingle. Cut vertically through the full-thickness areas and bend on the area where the bottom is single-ply.

Comment: Oh I got it. The problem is that single-ply area is not always aligned right in the center though... Hmm

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that. You may only get two out of a sheet. At any rate, you could just cut them in thirds and call it good. No problem there. Fold them on a warm day and you'll be happy.